# Why can my non group admin user see the Group tab on a group content type?

Tags: users, organic-groups

On my group content type, a member of the group can see the Group tab next to the View tab. When the user clicks on it, all they get is the group overview page without any links on it.

The issue is that members who are no an owner or admin of the group should not be able to even see the group tab.

I've gone over my global and group permissions many times and I have not seen anything that gives members any kind of admin access. I don't have anything configured for the tabs in views. (Except from og extras for the Members tab, I set that tab to only show if the user has group admin perms.)

Would one of the group "view" permissions make that tab show?

Anyway, I've spent a few hours on this now, so it's time to move on to something else for a while and come back to it with fresh eyes. Hopefully someone can help me out. Even if it's just a place too look.

Edit:
I'm not sure it's related, but when the non-member views the group tab, php spits out this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: title in theme_admin_block_content() (line 2455 of /path/to/drupal/modules/system/system.admin.inc).
```

I did Google that error, but I have yet to find anything useful.

End edit.

Here's my drush make file so you can see what I'm running:

```
; This file was auto-generated by drush make
core = 7.x
api = 2

; Core
projects[drupal][version] = "7.42"

; Modules

projects[addressfield][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[addressfield][version] = "1.1"

projects[admin_menu][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[admin_menu][version] = "3.0-rc5"

projects[adminimal_admin_menu][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[adminimal_admin_menu][version] = "1.7"

projects[bootstrap_fieldgroup][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[bootstrap_fieldgroup][version] = "1.2"

projects[ctools][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[ctools][version] = "1.9"

projects[cas][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[cas][version] = "1.5"

projects[cas_attributes][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[cas_attributes][version] = "1.0-rc3"

projects[cas_roles][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[cas_roles][version] = "1.2"

projects[comment_og][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[comment_og][version] = "1.0"

projects[crumbs][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[crumbs][version] = "2.x-dev"

projects[ctools][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[ctools][version] = "1.9"

projects[enforce_revlog][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[enforce_revlog][version] = "1.2"

projects[entity][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[entity][version] = "1.6"

projects[entityreference][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[entityreference][version] = "1.1"

projects[eva][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[eva][version] = "1.2"

projects[features][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[features][version] = "2.7"

projects[features_extra][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[features_extra][version] = "1.0"

projects[features_roles_permissions][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[features_roles_permissions][version] = "1.2"

projects[field_collection][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[field_collection][version] = "1.0-beta8"

projects[field_group][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[field_group][version] = "1.5"

projects[flag][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[flag][version] = "3.7"

projects[file_entity][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[file_entity][version] = "2.x-dev"

projects[htmlpurifier][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[htmlpurifier][version] = "1.0"

projects[inline_entity_form][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[inline_entity_form][version] = "1.6"

projects[jquery_update][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[jquery_update][version] = "3.0-alpha3"

projects[libraries][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[libraries][version] = "2.2"

projects[linkit][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[linkit][version] = "3.5"

projects[login_destination][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[login_destination][version] = "1.1"

projects[module_filter][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[module_filter][version] = "2.0"

projects[og][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[og][version] = "2.8"

projects[og_extras][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[og_extras][version] = "1.2"

projects[og_massadd][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[og_massadd][version] = "1.0-beta2"
projects[og_massadd][patch][] = "https://www.drupal.org/files/fixed-user-permission-1946320-7.patch"

projects[og_menu][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[og_menu][version] = "3.0"

projects[og_visibility][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[og_visibility][version] = "1.x-dev"

projects[og_vocab][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[og_vocab][version] = "1.2"

projects[panels][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[panels][version] = "3.5"

projects[panels_bootstrap_layouts][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[panels_bootstrap_layouts][version] = "3.x-dev"

projects[pathauto][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[pathauto][version] = "1.3"

projects[pathologic][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[pathologic][version] = "3.1"

projects[plupload][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[plupload][version] = "1.7"

projects[privatemsg][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[privatemsg][version] = "1.4"

projects[profile2][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[profile2][version] = "1.3"

projects[quicktabs][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[quicktabs][version] = "3.x-dev"

projects[realname][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[realname][version] = "1.2"

projects[rules][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[rules][version] = "2.9"

projects[safeword][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[safeword][version] = "1.13"

projects[strongarm][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[strongarm][version] = "2.x-dev"

projects[talk][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[talk][version] = "1.0"

projects[token][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[token][version] = "1.6"

projects[user_dashboard][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[user_dashboard][version] = "1.4"

projects[uuid][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[uuid][version] = "1.0-beta1"

projects[views][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[views][version] = "3.13"

projects[views_bootstrap][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[views_bootstrap][version] = "3.1"

projects[views_bulk_operations][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[views_bulk_operations][version] = "3.3"

projects[wysiwyg][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[wysiwyg][version] = "2.x-dev"


; Themes
projects[adminimal_theme][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[adminimal_theme][version] = "1.23"
projects[adminimal_theme][type] = "theme"

projects[bootstrap][subdir] = "contrib"
projects[bootstrap][version] = "3.0"
projects[bootstrap][type] = "theme"

; Libraries
; Please fill the following out. Type may be one of get, git, bzr or svn,
; and url is the url of the download.
;libraries[html_encoder][download][type] = ""
;libraries[html_encoder][download][url] = ""
;libraries[html_encoder][directory_name] = "html_encoder"
;libraries[html_encoder][type] = "library"

; phpCAS
libraries[CAS][download][type] = "git"
libraries[CAS][download][url] = "https://github.com/Jasig/phpCAS.git"
libraries[CAS][download][branch] = "1.3-stable"
libraries[CAS][directory_name] = "CAS"
libraries[CAS][type] = "library"

; plupload
libraries[plupload][download][type] = "get"
libraries[plupload][download][url] = "https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/archive/v1.5.8.zip"
libraries[plupload][directory_name] = "plupload"
libraries[plupload][type] = "library"

; jquery.blockui
libraries[jquery.blockui][download][type] = "get"
libraries[jquery.blockui][download][url] = "http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js"
libraries[jquery.blockui][directory_name] = "jquery.blockui"
libraries[jquery.blockui][type] = "library"

; CKEditor
libraries[CKEditor][download][type] = "get"
libraries[CKEditor][download][url] = "http://download.cksource.com/CKEditor/CKEditor/CKEditor%204.5.3/ckeditor_4.5.3_full.zip"
libraries[CKEditor][directory_name] = "ckeditor"
libraries[CKEditor][type] = "library"

; htmlpurifier
libraries[htmlpurifier][download][type] = "get"
libraries[htmlpurifier][download][url] = "http://htmlpurifier.org/releases/htmlpurifier-4.7.0.tar.gz"
libraries[htmlpurifier][directory_name] = "htmlpurifier"
libraries[htmlpurifier][type] = "library"
```

Comment: Not posting as an answer because I can't test but if I remember correctly, one of the views created by "Og Extras" can cause this. Try disabling the module to see if that's it and if it is, disable the appropriate view. Maybe.

Comment: I went through those views several times to figure out which was causing the problem. But I only able to fix the members tab issue. I couldn't find anything in those views about the groups tab. But I'll go check again.

Comment: After disabling every single view on my site, the Group tab is still there for a non-member. I even told page manager to stop overriding the group content type, it didn't help.

Comment: This appears to be the solution: https://www.drupal.org/node/1946320#comment-7762707 I need to remember that turning modules off and on is a good troubleshooting step sooner next time.